# how to redirect to login page and back again in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I want to ask about wordpress...

I have a scenario like this : if the user is not logged in, he should be redirected to login/reg page and back again to destination of the request page.
I use this code but can not get the destination url.

**code in page that restricted:**

```
if (user-no-login){wp_redirect( get_option('home') . '?redirect_to=' . esc_url($_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]) );}
```

and **login code**, I try to echo but just get `<site_url>/?page=login` as `($_REQUEST['redirect_to'])` when it should be `<site_url>/food/rice?red=1`.

Anyone can help me with my issue? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you're missing for this is [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) along with [wp_login_url](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_login_url)

```
if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
    wp_redirect( wp_login_url( $redirect ) );
    exit();
}
```

Note: The $redirect variable "**must be absolute** as in http://example.com/mypage/" so in this case: `$redirect = "http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST].$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]`.

Answer (score -1):

Create a page template. With this code on top:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Redirect
*/
?>
<?php if (!is_user_logged_in())
{
    header("Location: http://example.com/wp-login.php");
}
else
{
    get_header();
    //page code
    get_footer();
}?>
```

Comment: SeeBeen : Thank you for your assistance but how to distribute the URL that destination of user??? Because for your code, just direct to login form... Thank you

Comment: @JuanLie You can try this plugin - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/peters-login-redirect/